# Can I use Fate Transfer to make a Thing in the Ice transform immediately?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [Thing in the Ice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thing%20in%20the%20Ice) with 4 ice counters on it and played [Fate Transfer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fate%20Transfer) to move all these counters on to another creature, will it transform? Or is the check on how many counters it has done before the actual move of all the counters?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I guess they're careful on how they worded it now to avoid a Dark Depths scenario :D

Comment: I'm still waiting for that elusive "You may reorder the stack. Draw a card." instant for U... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

End result: Thing in the Ice with no counters, unflipped; another creature has 3 ice counters.

The sequence of events creates the following stack:

- Thing in the Ice Trigger
- Fate Transfer

The trigger is on top of the transfer since it is in response to the spell. Trigger resolves, removes 1 counter, sees that there are 3 counters left and doesn't flip. Transfer resolves, and moves the counters.  Since the trigger is already resolved, it doesn't flip.

The next time you cast an instant or sorcery, the trigger will (attempt to) remove a counter, then seeing no counters will flip.

Comment: It would still be a pretty hilarious play in a Thing In the Ice mirror though.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not work.

Thing in the Ice transforms from its triggered ability. The following will happen when you cast Fate Transfer as you described (assuming each player passes priority and no other effects happen):

- Fate Transfer is cast, targets are chosen, and it goes on the stack.
- State based actions are checked (creatures at zero toughness die, players with zero life lose the game unless an effect prevents it, etc)
- Triggered abilities go on the stack in APNAP (active player, non-active player) order
- Thing in the Ice has a triggered ability as just described. This ability goes on the stack on top of the Fate Transfer you just cast.
- Players receive priority in APNAP order. If all players pass priority, the effect on top of the stack resolves.
- The triggered ability from Thing in the Ice will resolve first because it is on top of the stack. You remove an Ice counter, if there are no more ice counters on Thing in the Ice then it will transform. In this case you remove 1 Ice counter, leaving 3. There are more than zero Ice counters left so Thing in the Ice does not transform.
- State based actions are checked again
- Players again receive priority in APNAP order. If all players pass priority, the effect on top of the stack resolves.
- Fate Transfer resolves and will move the remaining 3 counters from Thing in the Ice to the other creature you targeted (again assuming no other effects) leaving zero Ice counters on Thing in the Ice. However, it will not transform because nothing is telling it to (its triggered ability which checks if it should transform already resolved)

If you cast another instant or sorcery spell after Fate Transfer resolves, Thing in the Ice will flip because its ability that causes it to flip will trigger again.